# Can I see everything I have Checked Out?

Tags: check-out

In SharePoint 13 is there a way for me to view every document I have checked out from one location?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

- Go to Library setting
- Create new view
- Give it a name
- Click on **filter** section
- Select column `'Checked Out To'`
- Select `'Équals to'` operator
- Assign value as `[Me]`
- Go to **Folders** Section
- Click items without folder
- Click Save

Now open the library you will be able to see documents checked out to you.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the proper permissions you can see what files are checked out by going to  Settings > manage files which have no checked in version on the particular document library.

You can also run a custom report if you are a site admin that allows you to search for your user and check out and check in items. Found under Site Collection Administration> Audit Log reports > Run Custom reports.
[image]